# If else condition for go to next page in jmeter

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter

I need to use a if controller where i can put the condition for go to the next page(pagination) on the listing page of a ecommerce website. not so familiar with it. can anyone tell me that what condition should be here for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the logic which should be executed if function or variable is "true" as a child of the If Controller

- If Controller (condition: "${SOME_VARIABLE}"=="Some Value")

  - HTTP Request (open a page)

So **HTTP Request** will be executed only if `SOME_VARIABLE` equals `Some Value`

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more information on using the IF Controller.

If you need to go though all pages of your e-commerce website perhaps it would be better to use [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) instead